# Does Job 32:2 suggest that Elihu was a Hebrew?

Tags: job-iyov-book-of

The verse in question:

> But Elihu son of Barakel the Buzite, of the family of Ram, became very angry with Job for justifying himself rather than God.

Elihu's mini-genealogy is most familial information we're given about anyone in the book. Is there any significance to this? Is this verse's Ram to be identified with Hezron's son?

Answer (score 1):

The significance is to show that he was a descendant of Avraham.

See [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.32.2?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Job.32.2.1&lang2=bi) there:

> ממשפחת רם. אברהם שנאמר האדם הגדול בענקים (יהושע י״ד:ט״ו) זה אברהם
>
> Of the family of Ram - Abraham, as it is stated ([Josh. 14:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.14.15)): “the greatest man among the Anakim.” This is Abraham.

Likewise, [Targum Iyov 32:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.32.2?lang=bi&p2=Aramaic_Targum_to_Job.32.2&lang2=bi) which expressly mentions this.

The term "רם", the [Metzudos Dovid](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.32.2?lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_David_on_Job.32.2.2&lang2=bi) explains is because:

> כי רם היה מזרע בוז
>
> Because he was "elevated" due to the fact that he was a descendant of Buz

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Lol sorry @ezra

Comment: Note that Genesis 22:20-21 says Buz was a nephew of Abraham